# I want to copy files at the bottom of the folder hierarchy and put them in one folder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Analytics, I want to copy files at the bottom of the folder hierarchy and put them in one folder.
The files you want to copy are located in their respective folders.
(There are 21 files in total.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvp2D.png)

I tried it using ability to flatten the hierarchy of "Copy" activity.
However, as you can see in the attached image, the file name is created on the Synapse side.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULMVW.png)

I tried to get the name of the bottom-level file with the "Get Metadata" activity, but I could not use wildcards in the file path.

I considered creating and running 21 pipelines that would copy each file, but since the files are updated daily in Blob, it would be impractical to run the pipeline manually every day using 21 folder paths.

Does anyone know of any smart way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all the 21 file folders inside the `Intage Sample` folder?

Comment: Yes, all the 21 file folders are inside the **Intage Sample** folder and each folder has a folder like 2022071123731.zip.

Answer (score 1):

Using `flatten hierarchy` does not preserve existing file name, new file name will be generated. **Wildcard paths** are not accepted by `Get metadata` activity. Hence one option is to use `Get Metadata` with `ForEach` to achieve the requirement.

- The following are the images of folder structure that I used for this demonstration.

[image]

[image]

- I created a `Get Metadata` activity first. I am retrieving the folder names (21 folders like '20220701122731.zip') inside `Intage Sample` folder using field list as **child items**.

[image]

- Now I used `ForEach` activity to loop through these folders names by giving items value as `@activity('Get folders level1').output.childItems`.

[image]

- Inside `ForEach` I have 3 activities. First is another `Get Metadata` activity to get the subfolder names (to get one folder inside '20220701122731.zip', that is '20220701122731')

[image]

- In this, while creating dataset, we passed the name of parent folder (folder_1 = '20220701122731.zip') to the dataset to use it in the path as

```
@{concat('unzipped/Intage Sample.zip/Intage Sample/',dataset().folder_1)}
```

[image]

- This returns the names of subfolders (like '20220701122731') which are inside parent folder (like '20220701122731.zip' which have 1 subfolder each). I used `set variable` activity to assign the `child items` output to this variable using `@activity('Get folder inner').output.childItems` .

[image]

- The final step is copy activity to move the required files to one single destination folder. Since there is only one sub-folder inside each of the 21 folders (`only one sub-folder like '20220701122731' inside folder like '20220701122731.zip'`), we can use the values achieved from above steps directly to complete the copy.
- Along with the help of wildcard paths in this `copy data` activity, we can complete the copy. The wildcard directory path will be

```
@{concat('unzipped/Intage Sample.zip/Intage Sample/',item().name, '/', variables('test')[0].name)}

#item().name give parent folder name, in your case- '20220701122731.zip'

#variables('test')[0].name gives sub-folder name, in your case like '20220701122731'
```

[image]

- For sink, I have created a dataset pointing to a folder inside my container called `output_files`. When triggered, the pipeline runs successfully.

[image]

- The following are the contents of my `output_files` folder.

[image]